# Finding the max value for a column, grouped by a column in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

[image: Schemea]

I'm trying to write a query for the above database/tables that will return each directors highest ranking movie.

I've tried:

```
SELECT d.id, md.movie_id, m.name, m.year, MAX(m.rank)
FROM directors d
INNER JOIN movies_directors md
ON d.id = md.director_id
INNER JOIN movies m
ON md.movie_id = m.id
GROUP BY d.id
```

but it is returning:

```
[Code: 8120, SQL State: S0001]  Column 'movies_directors.movie_id' is invalid in the select list 
because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a top-1-per-group problem. Instead of aggregating, you need some kind of filtering logic.

You can typically use `row_number()` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        d.id, 
        md.movie_id, 
        m.name, 
        m.year, 
        row_number() over(partition by d.id order by m.rank desc) rn
    from directors d
    inner join movies_directors md on d.id = md.director_id
    inner join movies m on md.movie_id = m.id
) t
where rn = 1
```